# Stylesheet issue in MMA 11

Tags: front-end, stylesheet

In my custom stylesheet that I use for all my notebooks, I had a definition of the style for graphics that looked like so:

```
Cell[StyleData["Graphics"],
 CellFrame->False,
 TextAlignment->Center,
 TextJustification->0.,
 MenuSortingValue->10000,
 FontFamily->"Times New Roman",
 FontSize->12,
 Background->None,
 GraphicsBoxOptions->{ImageSize->600}]
```

to set my default font for graphics, and to have the graphics appear centered. This worked fine in Mma10, and resulted in centered graphics. In Mma11, there's a minor issue in that the graphics do not appear centered anymore, but the much more major issue is that using the new `Callout` command causes series of error messages and ultimately makes the graphics fail:

```
ListPlot[Table[Callout[i, i], {i, 1, 5}]]

ImageDimensions::imginv: Expecting an image or graphics instead of Internal`PartitionRagged({},{1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0}).

ImageResize::imginv: Expecting an image or graphics instead of Internal`PartitionRagged({},{1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0}).

ImageDimensions::imginv: Expecting an image or graphics instead of Internal`PartitionRagged({},{1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0}).

ImageResize::imginv: Expecting an image or graphics instead of Internal`PartitionRagged({},{1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0}).

ImageDimensions::imginv: Expecting an image or graphics instead of Internal`PartitionRagged({},{1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0}).

General::stop: Further output of ImageDimensions::imginv will be suppressed during this calculation.

ImageResize::imginv: Expecting an image or graphics instead of Internal`PartitionRagged({},{1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0}).

General::stop: Further output of ImageResize::imginv will be suppressed during this calculation.

Part::partw: Part {1,2,3,4,5} of {} does not exist.

MapThread::mptd: Object {}[[{1,2,3,4,5}]] at position {2, 3} in MapThread[Charting`CommonDump`renderCalloutLabels(#1,#2,#3,{Automatic},#4,({1.,1.}  {2.,2.} {3.,3.} {4.,4.} {5.,5.}),{1,2,3,4,5},{},{300,300/\[Phi]},None,(0.   5.
0   5.

),{0.,0},1/\[Phi],(Scaled[0.02] Scaled[0.08]
Scaled[0.02]    Scaled[0.097082039]

),False)&,{(1.  1.
2.  2.
3.  3.
4.  4.
5.  5.

),{{1->Internal`PartitionRagged({},{1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0})},<<3>>,{5->Internal`PartitionRagged({},{<<1>>})}},<<1>>,({}
{}
{}
{}
{}

)}] has only 0 of required 1 dimensions.
```

If I take the two lines

```
 TextAlignment->Center,
 TextJustification->0.,
```

out, everything works fine. Is this a bug? Any way to work around this? It's not the end of the world, but having my graphics appear centered on the notebook page automatically would be nice.

P.S.: Doing something like:

```
CellPrint[
 ExpressionCell[ListPlot[Table[Callout[i, i], {i, 1, 5}]], "Output", 
  TextAlignment -> Center]]
```

works fine, however. Still, I'd like to have those things in the stylesheet, so I don't need to repeat them all the time in my input.

Comment: Yup, I'm seeing this on Mathematica 11 on Windows. I would contact Tech Support and let them know you've found a possible bug, http://www.wolfram.com/support/contact/email/?topic=Technical

Comment: O.k., sent them a note.